How to upgrade Magento2 community version to Adobe commerce cloud
I have one website in Magento2 Community edition 2.4.3 ,i want to migrate the website from Magento2 community edition to Adobe commerce cloud 2.4.3 which steps i need to follow, can someone guide me.

You can use official dcomentation to do it
See: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade
